# Using a variable instead of the fieldname

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have 4 Custom fields in Microsoft project.  "Optimistic", "MostLikely" and "Pessimistic" are required CustomNames for any 3 of the Duration fields. "CriticalCnt" is also a required Custom Name for any of the 20 Number fields. I have a routine which identifies the Microsoft Project Fieldname which has been customized which I have assigned to a variable.
When I am looking for the values for these fields for each task, I want to use the variable to identify the field.

I have researched the Web for `"ProjectSummaryTask","FieldConstantToFieldname",FieldnametoFieldConstant"` with no luck.

What I want to do is to do the following:

```
Dim i as integer, fieldvalue as long, Tsk as Task
For I = 1 to ActiveProject.task.count do
    Fieldvalue =Activeproject.Task.CriticalCnt
    Debug.print ("Task=" & Task(i).id & " Task(i).CriticalCnt=" & 
    Task(i).CriticalCnt)
next i
```

This routine gets the 9 digit code to identify the CustomNamed field.  In this case, Number4 was assigned the CustomName of "CriticalCnt". I have no idea what is being updated in this routine with the Value 3.

```
Sub GetFieldID()

Dim Projectfield As Long, ProjectFieldName As String, Message As String, i 
As Integer, tasks As tasks, t As Long, NT As Long, tmp As tasks, criticalCnt 
As String

Projectfield = FieldNameToFieldConstant("CriticalCnt", pjDuration)
Message = "ProjectfieldNumber = " & Projectfield & vbCrLf
MsgBox Message & ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.GetField(Projectfield)
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldID:=Projectfield, Value:="3"
ProjectFieldName = FieldConstantToFieldName(Projectfield)
Message = "New Value for Field:" & ProjectFieldName & vbCrLf
MsgBox Message & ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.GetField(Projectfield)
Set tasks = ActiveProject.tasks
NT = tasks.Count

Debug.Print ("NT=" & NT)
    For t = 1 To NT
        Debug.Print ("T=" & t)
        Debug.Print (".id = " & tasks(t).ID & " Value= " & Projectfield & _
        " tasks(t).Projectfield= " & Projectfield)
        Debug.Print ("Value=" & _
        ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.GetField(Projectfield))
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the CriticalCnt field contain the field ID of one of the three customized Duration fields? (e.g. Duration1 = 188743783, Duration5 = 188743956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function finds the number field customized with the name "CriticalCnt" and uses it to identify which of the three customized duration fields contains the correct duration for each task and outputs each task's ID with its custom duration. Note that CriticalCnt contains the *field ID* of the customized duration field (a nine-digit number).

```
Sub GetCustomDuration()

' Schedule contains 4 customized fields--1 number field and 3 duration fields.
' The duration fields are named "Optimistic", "MostLikely" and "Pessimistic".
' Each task uses one of these fields and the selected one is identified in the
' customized number field called "CriticalCnt" which contains its field ID.


' find the field customized to contain the CriticalCnt data
Dim fldCriticalCnt As Long
fldCriticalCnt = Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant("CriticalCnt")

Dim tsk As Task
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks

    ' determine which of the three duration fields to use for this task
    Dim fldCustomDur As Long
    fldCustomDur = CLng(tsk.GetField(fldCriticalCnt))

    ' get the custom duration value
    Dim CustomDur As String
    CustomDur = tsk.GetField(fldCustomDur)

    Debug.Print "Task=" & tsk.ID & " CriticalCnt=" & CustomDur _
        & " (" & DurationValue(CustomDur) & " minutes)"
Next tsk

End Sub
```

Note: It would seem that storing the *name* of the custom duration field rather than the field ID would be better for end-user. In this case CriticalCnt would be a text field customized with a drop-down list of three items: "Optimistic", "MostLikely" and "Pessimistic".

Comment: Every task uses all 3 duration fields and 1 Number field.   The 3 duration fields may be any of the 10 available duration fields  (customNameed= Optimisitic, MostLikely and Pessimistic) and any one of the 20 available number fields (CustomNamed= CriticalCnt). Each task has a value for each of these 4 customnamed fields.

Comment: So, for any one task there are 4 fields used to hold its data..  When I add fldCustomDur to the Debug Statement, the correct value prints out for the Number field.  When I run the routine Looking for "Optimistic" custom Name ( It is Duration1), I get an error 13 for a type mismatch on the fldCustomDur=CLng(tsk.Getfield(flsCriticalCnt)) statement.  The value shown for fldCriticalCnt is 188743783, which is correct for Duration1. Durations are not always integer but may also be fractional days.

Comment: I looked up CLng and it is a rounding function to convert a value to an integer.  I am not sure that is the function I want to apply, but this is getting much closer than I have been.  Thank you.  I hope you are able to help me with solving the GetField statement working for the 3 duration fields.  I have been struggling with this for 2 weeks. Thank you.

Comment: Duration fields have their duration converted to minutes and held as integer minutes.  To convert to days, you divide by " /60/8" to get the duration.

Comment: @dgr The `GetField` function returns a string--it returns the field value as shown in the UI, so duration fields will be returned as displayed and why it is appropriate to explicitly convert the number field to a number. The code presumes the CriticalCnt field contains a valid field ID. If it contains something else, update your question to reflect what is actually contained.

Comment: I see what is happening.  The getfield command reads the displayed view on the screen.  Durations are shown as 10d, 10 days, etc.  I changed the Dim fldCustomDur as Long to a String type. Now, I get an error on the CustomDur=tsk.GetField((fld(customDur) statement, again type mismatch..  The value for fldCustomDur = 10 days.  Instead of using the CLng I used the CStr command.

Comment: maybe I have to remove the "d" or "days" part of the returned string?

Comment: See updated code which uses the [DurationValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.durationvalue) function to convert displayed duration to the number of minutes.

Comment: That is what I had to do-

Comment: Dim tsk As Task
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.tasks

    ' determine which of the three duration fields to use for this task
    Dim fldCustomDur As String
    fldCustomDur = CStr(tsk.GetField(fldCriticalCnt))
    

    ' get the custom duration value
    Dim CustomDur As String
    CustomDur = Left(fldCustomDur, InStr(fldCustomDur, " d"))

    Debug.Print "Task=" & tsk.ID & " CustomDur=" & CustomDur & " fldCustomDur=" & fldCustomDur & " FldCriticalCnt=" & fldCriticalCnt
Next tsk

Comment: works for all 3 duration fields and the Number field.  Thank you so much for giving me the lead I needed.

Comment: Glad this works for you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).